# react native and firebase [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-custom-token).]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am creating persistent user login however i keep on getting the same error of invalid token.Below is my code

I USETHESIGNINWITHEMAILANDPASSWORD METHOD OF FIREBASE.I GET THE TOKEN AND STORE IT IN ASYNC STORAGE.

```
   const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      );


 const token = await userCredential.user.getIdToken(true);
```

THIS IS THE USEEFFECT FOR WHERE I WANT TO CHECK WETHER THE USER TOKEN IS SILL VALID;

```
 useEffect(() => {
const chechUserPersists = async () => {
  try {
    const n = await AsyncStorage.getItem("user");
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("token");
    const user = await signInWithCustomToken(auth, token);
    console.log(user);
    if (!n) throw "User is not Logged In";
    console.log("user exists", n);
    dispatch(logUserIn());
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("not exists");
  }
};
chechUserPersists();


 }, []);
```

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {

};
```

THIS IS THE FIREBASE FILE
// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
export const auth = getAuth();

I KEEP ON GETTING THE SAME ERROR   [FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-custom-token).] . can you please point out the issue?